# org.slf4j.simpleLogger truncates log file at startup

Tags: java, slf4j

I am using slf4j SimpleLogger and my problem is that my log file is truncated at startup,
so that my previous log data is lost.

How do I prevent it from doing that?

My simplelogger.properties looks like this:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=kensa.log
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to append log entries with simple logger.

Use more advanced logging backed such as [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)